# How to handle a kinda bad question, when it already have been answered?

Tags: discussion

[Misconceptions about electric theory](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/15779/is-the-electric-theory-commonly-taught-completely-off)

I made the question about electric theory earlier this week. I am not entirely happy with the question, but I am very unsure what to do with it.

As pointed out in comments of the question, the question is a bit too big, and it's not just a single question. The question need some editing, but I have already received several answers. And it's already fairly big question, with a bit of attention now, and I advertised it on other stack-exchanges as well.

"Is what written on this page valid?"

"Is the current teaching lacking?`"

And also the unwritten question "Is lying/hiding, the best way to teach, and is the subject handled the correct way?"

**Problem A:**
I need to improve the question, I am unsure what to do with it. I can divide it into the three questions it is more clearly, or I can make it into one question and ask the other questions separately(or just scrap them). I would like some feedback on what to do with the question.

**Problem B:**
I have gotten 4 answers already. All of them answers some of the three questions, neither all three, and all the three questions is kinda answered. I need to edit the question, and accept an answer, but depending on which way I edit the question, either of those answers will be "correct", and some of them will be off. Also if I focus the question to be one question instead of all three, which of the questions is it most fitting that I change this one to?
How should I handle that, since I kinda will invalidize some of the answers?

Splitting the question means that you kinda get another question slightly similar, and some people think that is a duplicate. What IS the right way to handle this?

Answer (score 1):

The question I felt is most important is "Is information of this homepage valid?". Problem is that I got least satisfying answers about that.
I am thinking of doing a divide, and ask about knowledge and teachings as a separate question instead.

I can't decide how to handle things completely though.

I ended up splitting the question into two, but then I instead get complaints about the two questions being duplicates. I edited the question to be more clear, and the new question focuses on whenever or not that is being taught out.

Answer (score 0):

In this particular case I feel that [most upvoted answer](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/a/15785/3790) to the first question pretty much invalidated the second question. That's why I've marked second one as duplicate.

Duplicate doesn't have to mean, that it's exactly the same question, but also can mean that an answer to another question already answers this one. 
For example recently this question: [Is "Limitless" pill is for real?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/15735/is-limitless-pill-is-for-real) closed as duplicate of [Do we only use 10% of our brain?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/59/do-we-only-use-10-of-our-brain)

Comment: The limitless pill depends on the answer of 10% though, and depending on answer on the 10% the whole question might get invalidated. If answer to 10% question was "yes we only use 10% of our brain" the other question would be a possible question to ask. In this case I don't feel it's the same, but the last angle was kinda uninteresting.

Comment: It IS disheartening to get downvoted, and voted for closing within minutes of question appearing, without any real explanation. "Duplicate of X", when X is being linked in question, just makes you look stupid. Unless you explain WHY you think it's a duplicate, or more thought process, then your actions is only negative, and contains close to no feedback at all.